# Firebase Cloud Messaging Not Received by TestFlight Users - iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When sending push notifications from the firebase console, beta testers with access to the application through TestFlight do not receive the notification.

Before adding the app store ID to the GoogleService-Info.plist file, the only device to receive the notification was the one registered in app store connect.

After adding the app store ID, the device registered as well as the one additional user on the app store connect team's device received the notification.

There are an additional 100+ users that have not received the notification although firebase shows that it was sent.

It is also worth noting that the GoogleService-Info.plist file has not been updated on the project yet.

**Is there any additional configuration that needs to be done to ensure that all users in a segment receive the notification?**

I will test another push after sending another update with the new GoogleService-Info.plist added to the project and update if that solves the problem.

Comment: Did you enable push notifications in app capabilities? Is push notification exist in your AppName.entitlements file?

Comment: Push notifications are enabled in the app capabilites, APS Environment in the entitlements file is set to development. Sounds like that could be the issue. I imagine setting this to production will do the trick. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by setting the APS Environment to "Production".

Thank you @Kstin